# Should I answer in spanish, then add the english translation? ¿Debería yo responder en español y añadir traducción al inglés?

Tags: discusión, respuestas

There are often questions in english, where I'm answering in english.

I'm spanish, but I can handle well english. So, I wonder if it would be better if I answer in spanish and add a translation to english.

Is there any consensus on this?

---

A menudo hay preguntas hechas en inglés, a las que yo estoy respondiendo en inglés.

Soy español, y me manejo bien con el inglés. Por tanto, me pregunto si sería mejor si respondo en español y añado una traducción al inglés.

¿Hay algo consensuado al respecto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Originalmente mucha gente iba escribiendo sus respuestas tanto en inglés como en castellano.

Pero es muchísimo trabajo en el caso de las muchas respuestas de más de una o dos oraciones breves.  Por lo tanto, lo normal ha sido responder en el idioma en que está escrita la pregunta.